# automorphism of a rooted tree

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Nowadays i'm working with tree automorphisms. I couldn't find information about rooted tree automorphism concerning the root.

Does an automorphism of a rooted tree fix the root or not? Logically it must fix the root but i couldn't be sure of it.

Thanks,

Comment: In any normal case, one would require an automorphism of a rooted tree to fix the root.

Answer (score 1):

> Does an automorphism of a rooted tree fix the root or not?

Given that for any rooted tree, its root is a distinguished node, any automorphism **must** fix the root. Otherwise it would be a matter of automorphisms of a tree.